# bluemix sendgrid send email

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, sendgrid

I am trying to send a validation email with sendGrid. I have tried everything but it is not working. Is there someone who has experience with sendgrid and who could tell me what mistake i am making in my code ? I have left the email field empty now on purpose just want to know what is wrong in the code

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'lib/SendGrid.php';

if (isset($_REQUEST["email"])) {


    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $emailadr = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $role = $_POST['role']; 


$strsq0 = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, role) VALUES ('" . $name . "','" . $emailadr . "', SHA1('".$password."'), '" . $role . "');"; //query to insert new user
    if ($mysqli->query($strsq0)) {
        //header("Location: ../index.php");
    } else {
        echo "Cannot insert into the data table; check whether the table is created, or the database is active. "  . mysqli_error();
    }    


$sg_username = "";
$sg_password = "";


$sendgrid = new SendGrid( $sg_username, $sg_password );
$mail = new SendGrid\Email();


try {
    $mail->
    setFrom( "" )->
    addTo( "" )->
    setSubject( "This Is The Subject" )->
    setText( "Hello," )->
    setHtml( "" );

    $response = $sendgrid->send( $mail );

    if (!$response) {
        throw new Exception("Did not receive response.");
    } else if ($response->message && $response->message == "error") {
        throw new Exception("Received error: ".join(", ", $response->errors));
    } else {
        print_r($response);
    }
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    var_export($e);
}

}
```

Comment: Are you using the last version of the official Sendgrid PHP client library (https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php)? What error do you get?

Comment: Just to be sure since the older versions had some issues. What error do you get?

Comment: i am working on bluemix so I am getting aan 500 error. When there is a fault in the code you alwasy get the 500 code. I followed the tutorial of the link you send me it says that i should but sendgrid in the composer.json file and require the needed php in my php file? how do I know if composer installed al the libs ?

Comment: After the 'require' command you should be able to use the library objects. Otherwise you could also try without using composer (see "Alternative: Install from zip"). Did you analyze the application logs? (cf logs appName --recent)